# ARINC429 Word Construction

Tags: python, binary, cpu-word

Just as a preamble I am using python 3 and the bitstring library.

So Arinc429 words are 32 bit data words.

Bits 1-8 are used to store the label. Say for example I want the word to set the latitude, according to the label docs, set latitude is set to the octal

```
041
```

I can model this in python by doing:

```
label = BitArray(oct='041')
print(label.bin)
>> 000100001
```

The next two bits can be used to send a source, or extend the label by giving an equipment ID. Equipment IDs are given in hex, the one I wish to use is

```
002
```

So again, I add it to a new BitArray object and convert it to binary

```
>> 000000010
```

Next comes the data field which spans from bits 11-29. Say I want to set the latitude to the general area of London (51.5072). This is where I'm getting stuck as floats can only be 32/64 bits long.

There are 2 other parts of the word, but before I go there I am just wondering, if I am going along the right track, or way off how you would construct such a word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but you need to either know or decide the format for your data field.

If the 19 bits you want to represent a float are documented somewhere as being a float then look how that conversion is done (as that's not at all a standard number of bits for a floating point number). If those bits are free-form and you can choose both the encode and decode then just pick something appropriate.

There is a standard for 16-bit floats which is occasionally used, but if you only want to represent a latitude I'd go for something simpler. As it can only got from 0 to 360 just scale that to an integer from 0 to 2^19 and store the integer.

So 51.5072 becomes (51.5072/360*(2**19)) = 75012

Then store this as a unsigned integer

```
> latitude = BitArray(uint=75012, length=19)
```

This gives you a resolution of about 0.0007 degrees, which is the best you can hope for. To convert back:

```
> latitude.uint*360.0/2**19
51.50665283203125
```